# Nginx redirect top level domain

Tags: nginx, dns

I've just started using Nginx instead of apache.

I'm trying to find a similar way to do something like this, in Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But in Nginx.

So basically any .co.uk traffic gets redirected to .com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate `server` block for the `.co.uk` domain:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .example.co.uk;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details. Note that the `default_server` option can also be used to match *any* non-specific domain name.

Comment: Note regarding the leading dot: A special wildcard name in the form “.example.org” can be used to match both the exact name “example.org” and the wildcard name “*.example.org”. --  [NGiNX Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names)